# How to remove items from recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, retrofit

How can i remove item from recycler view adapter. I fetch items from api and store in recyclerview adapter.  I am using following code to delete the item in mysql database but unable to remove item from recyclerview

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.ordTxt.setText("Order No : "+mData.get(position).getOrderNumber());
        holder.ordCharges.setText("Rs: "+mData.get(position).getOrderCharges());

        orderNo = mData.get(position).getOrderNumber();


        holder.detBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent in_cat = new Intent(ctx,OrderDetail.class);
            in_cat.putExtra("user_id", preferenceHelper.getId());
            in_cat.putExtra("ordNo", mData.get(position).getOrderNumber());
            ctx.startActivity(in_cat);
        });

        holder.canBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            cancelConfirmation();

        });


    }

call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    //Log.i("Responsestring", response.body().toString());
                    //Toast.makeText(ctx, "Response Got", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {

                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            Log.i("onSuccess", response.body());

                            //deleteItem(mData.get(position));

                            String jsonresponse = response.body();
                            Toast.makeText(ctx,jsonresponse,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            //success message for cancelling order to be set here

                            //JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonresponse);
                            //if(obj.optString("status").equals("true")){


                            //parseLoginData(jsonresponse);

                        } else {

                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            Log.i("onEmptyResponse", "Returned empty response");
                            //Toast.makeText(ctx,"Empty Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ctx,"Please connect your internet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

I am using retrofit to call the api and remove the items in mysql, how can i get position of select item and remove it from recyclerview on success message from api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this would work `notifyItemRemoved(position)`

```
holder.canBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    cancelConfirmation(position);
});
```

Then pass as parameter of the current position as below  `cancelConfirmation(int position)` and finally when the response is successful remove the item as below

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    mData.remove(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter)

Comment: But i want to call this method after api response. if (response.isSuccessful()) { if (response.body() != null) { 
 After this

Comment: Ok,  does cancelConfirmation contain the api call?

Comment: yes it contains api call as defined in the code mentioned        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    //Log.i("Responsestring", response.body().toString());
                    //Toast.makeText(ctx, "Response Got", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {

                            progressDialog.dismiss();

Comment: when i remove items first time it is ok, but when i remove last item it causes error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

kotlin version:

```
private fun deleteItem(position: Int) {
    mDataSet.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataSet.size)
}
```

Comment: How to call this method after api response. if (response.isSuccessful()) { if (response.body() != null) { 
 After this